# Best way to store the sum of all node depths?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

To sum up all the nodes' depths in any given binary tree, I've written the following recursive algorithm:

```
def nodeDepths(root):
    final=[0]
    helper(root,0, final)
    return final[0]

def helper(node,d, final):
    if not node:
        return 
    final[0]+= d
    helper(node.left,d+1, final)
    helper(node.right,d+1, final)

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

My thinking was: as I see each node, add the depth of that node to the final sum, then recursively call on the left and right with `final` list as an argument. At the end of the recursive call stack, `final[0]` should have the right value.

Is there a better way to do this? I have concerns about thread safety in general with global variables but is it a better practice to use global variables in this case?

Comment: For those in the reopen queue. Python is only pass by value, by mutating the list you can hack pass by reference into Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PEP8

`nodeDepths` should be `node_depths` in snake_case.

### Function naming

`helper` is not a helpful name for a function. If I were to guess what this does, it should maybe be called `recurse_node_depths`.

### Instance methods

As it stands, `BinaryTree` does not deserve to have an `__init__`. It would be better-suited as a `@dataclass` or maybe a named tuple. That said, it probably makes more sense for `node_depths` to be an instance method where `self` replaces `root`.

### Integer-by-reference

My first read of this code was wrong. `final` is only ever going to have one member. My guess is that you did this to effectively pass an integer by reference, but this is a gross hack. Instead, just return the evolving sum as an integer from your recursion, and the uppermost return will be the total that you need.

### Slots

Another way to squeeze performance out of this is to initialize `__slots__` for `BinaryTree` based on the three known members.

### Recursion

Recursion is not a great idea in Python, for at least two reasons:

- Given that there is no indication to the maximum depth of your input tree, you may blow the stack.
- Since Python does not have tail recursion optimization, recursion is slower than some other languages.

So you should attempt to reframe this as an iterative implementation.